# PHP _google chart _ multiple files' data in 1 graph ... how to ? _ basic question

Tags: php, arrays, google-visualization, text-files, bar-chart

In google chart,

`<img src="<?php print $barChart->getUrl();  ?>" /> <br> for today.`  is used to create the img corresponding to the graph.

I have used LOOPS to read multiple text files, then extract values and put them in an array, then use this array to pass it to the `$barChart->addDataSet` function.

The problem is that only the graph for day 1 (i.e. file 1) gets displayed. Day 2 needs either:

1. I NEED to CREATE A NEW STACK FOR each file. How do I achieve this?
   or
2. I need to create separate graphs for each file on the same WEBPAGE. How do I achieve this?

Please help!!

It would be better if I can create a separate stack for each file.

Comment: This is really a php question, not google charts. However, can you show the output that gets sent to google? I know google charts well and might be able to help if I look at that (however, I don't know php at all)

Comment: The output that gets sent is `119y value ...
121y value ...
120y value ...
10y value ...
119y value ...
121y value ...
120y value ...
10y value ...
119y value ...
121y value ...
120y value ...
10y value ...
20y1 value ...
30y1 value ...
50y1 value ...
60y1 value ...
20y1 value ...
30y1 value ...
50y1 value ...
60y1 value ...
20y1 value ...
30y1 value ...
50y1 value ...
60y1 value ... `  ... pl assume that each stack has 8 blocks of 2 colors .. and hence in this case there needs to be 3 stacks totally ! PLease help... thanks